# GCDAsyncSocket receive data but cache automatic when run iPhone

Tags: ios, sockets, caching, memory, gcdasyncsocket

I use GCDAsyncSocket to receive data from server,in simulator it work ok, but in iPhone it cache data automatic， my iPhone memory become more and more huge, anybody know how to solve this problem?

Comment: Update your question with code you did for better clarification.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10611679/gcdasyncsocket-read-data-issue

the problem it's same like this one, but he's solve not explain why lead to this problem